# Is there a way to do 'interactive programming' in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, hot-reload

I found [this post on Null Program titled 'Interactive Programming in C'](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/12/23/) and I was wondering if there was a way to do that in OCaml.

I tried googling my goal, but I cannot seem to find any information related to it.

Comment: [OCaml has a REPL](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/toplevel.html). Isn't that interactive enough?

Comment: @Bergi I suspect you've pinpointed the exact reason why search engines were no help with this question. All mentions of "interactive" just bring up pages about REPL, which is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: Can you change how a function works at runtime? Yes, by altering persistent configuration data. _Should you?_ is firmly in the territory of opinion, but it would seem to rather conflict with the goals of OCaml, which the tag here sums up as: _OCaml is a strict statically-typed functional programming language, focusing on expressiveness, correctness, and efficiency._

Comment: @Stef "*I was wondering if there was a way to do that*" - I would argue that a language that implements a REPL does provide the tools necessary to redefine functions on the fly, which is what the OP is asking about. But for the development approach described in the article, the search terms would be "hot module reloading" and "hot code replacement".

Comment: @Stef https://www.google.com/search?q=ocaml+hot+reload finds https://jaredforsyth.com/posts/hot-reloading-ocaml-on-web-desktop-and-android, https://github.com/let-def/hotcaml and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article has several points whose conjunction it calls "interactive programming"

- put most of your application logic in a shared library

  - Yes Ocaml can do that. If you create your project with `dune init`, the produced directory structure is naturally adapted for this structure
- No global mutable state, pass state around.

  - Obviously this is doable (store the state in a struct). In Ocaml it is more natural to return a new state instead of mutating a state you’d pass around.
  - The inner structure of the state can similarly be kept private, in Oacml this is called an [abstract type](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs3110/2021sp/textbook/modules/abstract_types.html)
- Reload the library in realtime while it is being modified

  - Yes it [can be done](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Dynlink.html). From what I get, you would have to reload it with `loadfile_private` and have it update a table of functions
  - Is it a good idea? not sure. You would lose some benifits of type-safety, but why not?